# Laravel: how to set one property on a pivot table, unset all others

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, laravel-5.1

I have a many to many relationship set up, between locations and stations. A location can have many assigned stations, but only one can be active. I have a pivot table (station_location) where i'm setting an is_active attribute using a setActive method, however i'm trying to figure out a sensible way to approach setting one to active, and all others to inactive.

I need this to be reusable as i'll have to set it in multiple places (not just from a controller). I wonder if anybody has an idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Extend your setActive method in your model to set all other locations to inactive before setting one to active?

Comment: Firstly, are you sure it's a many-to-many? Can a station have many locations?

Comment: @daveyWavey Yes, multiple stations can be used by multiple locations and switched to active as a backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sync` method as below

```
$station->locations()
->sync([1 => ['is_active' => true], 2 => ['is_active' => false], 3 => ['is_active' => false]]);
```

more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships)

PS: 1,2,3 etc in passed array are locations ids.